# Autoclave pressure - how many PSI will lift my lid?

Tags: pressure

I am a mushroom enthusiast who is trying to build a cheap autoclave to sterilize my substrate before inoculation.

The autoclave is basically just a chamber of a cubic shape where I pump steam.

Size is 48" x 48" x 48"
The bottom, 4 walls and lid are all made of a 1" steel sheets.

The lid has a machined groove filled with a high temperature resistant rubber cord to act as a seal.
The lid is not bolted to the structure nor attached in any way. The lid is simply sitting on top of the 4 walls aligned with the groove.

The lid weight is 489 lbs
The lid exposed surface to the inner chamber is 46" x 46".

When running, the pressure will build up in the chamber.
So now my question; how many PSI will it reach inside the chamber before the 489 lbs lid measuring 46" x 46" will be lifted by the pressure build up?

Comment: About 0.25 psi over atmosphere, plus or minus any friction/stiction of the lid...

Answer (score 3):

A 46" x 46" piece of steel has a surface area of 46in * 46in = 2,116 square inches.  If the pressure needs to lift 489 pounds, the pressure needed will be 489 pounds  / 2116sq. inches = 0.2310 pounds per square inch (psi)

Of course, this situation will never occur, because you will re-design the autoclave to never try to lift a 489 pound block of steel.  If anything binds as the pressure rises, then the pressure can get much higher than a quarter PSI.  If it lets go at an inopportune moment, the question you will be asking  is how will *you* catch a 489 pound block of steel?  *This is a trick question.  Don't set yourself up to need to answer it!*

So instead, you should do what pressure cookers do.  They have a steam escape valve that is calibrated to maintain a reasonable pressure.  You apply a healthy safety margin on that 0.23psi from above, and design a steam release valve which maintains that lower pressure, letting steam escape if it gets higher than that.  It is much easier to do this safely with a small device that can be tested than to do this safely with a 489 pound block of steel.

You should also have a trusted failsafe which lets the pressure go before it becomes dangerous.  I am no expert in pressure chambers, so I cannot suggest a specific one.  But I can say that there is a *decided* interest in the community in ensuring that pressure vessels stay safe, so there are going to be plenty of designs which are trustworthy to release the pressure before it becomes dangerous.